# Using meshgrid in MATLAB when the function has matrix operations

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to plot level surfaces of a 3 variable function. The variables are in a column vector **X = [x, y, z]^t**. The function is **f(X) = X^t * A * X**. Where **^t** means transpose and **A** is a 3x3 constant matrix. I know for a fact that **A** is symmetric and therefore diagonalizable, i.e. **A = V * D * V^t**. Just in case it turns out to be useful.

I intend to use isosurface to get the points of the function where it equals a certain level and then use patch to plot.

However I can't figure out how to compute the value of the function for every point in the grid. Ideally I'd like to do

```
x = linspace(-1, 1,10); y=x; z = x;
[XX,YY,ZZ]=meshgrid(x,y,z);
f = [XX YY ZZ]'*A*[XX YY ZZ];
level = 1;
s = isosurface(XX,YY,ZZ,f,level);
patch(s, 'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','blue');
```

but this won't work obviously because of the sizes of XX and A. What I've done so far is do the math myself to obtain the function as a polynomial of XX, YY and ZZ but it's incredibly ugly and not practical.

Anybody knows how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this does that you want. In the following explanation I will use 10x10x10 points as given in your example (although the code works for any number of points). Also, I define a random 3x3 matrix `A`.

Once `XX`,  `YY` and `ZZ` have been generated as 10x10x10 arrays (step 1), the key is to build a 1000x3 matrix in which the first column is *x* coordinate, the second is *y* and the third is *z*. This is variable `XYZ` in the code below (step 2).

Since `XYZ` is a matrix, not a vector, the function `f` can't be computed using matrix multiplication. But it can be obtained efficiently with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). First compute an intermediate 1000x3x3 variable (`XYZ2`) with all 3x3 products of coordinates for each of the 1000 points (step 3). Then reshape it into a 1000x9 matrix and multiply by the 9x1 vector obtained from linearizing `A` (step 4).

The `f` thus obtained has size 1000x1. You need to reshape it into a 10x10x10 array to match `XX`, `YY` and `ZZ` (step 5). Then you can use [`isosurface`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html) as per your code (step 6).

```
A = rand(3);
x = linspace(-1, 1,10); y = x; z = x;
[XX,YY,ZZ] = meshgrid(x,y,z);                        %// step 1
XYZ = [XX(:) YY(:) ZZ(:)];                           %// step 2
XYZ2 = bsxfun(@times, XYZ, permute(XYZ, [1 3 2]));   %// step 3
f = reshape(XYZ2,[],numel(A))*A(:);                  %// step 4
f = reshape(f, size(XX));                            %// step 5
level = 1;
s = isosurface(XX,YY,ZZ,f,level);
patch(s, 'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','blue');     %// step 6
```

Comment: Aaaw, yours is faster:(

Comment: And it turns out that it's as fast as `ffun2 = @(x,y,z) x.^2*A(1,1)+y.^2*A(2,2)+z.^2*A(3,3)+2*x.*y*A(1,2)+2*x.*z*A(1,3)+2*y.*z*A(2,3); f=ffun2(XX,YY,ZZ);`

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that you could explicitly define your function as

```
ffun = @(x,y,z) [x y z]*A*[x; y; z];
```

then use `arrayfun` to apply this function to each element of your coordinate vectors:

```
f = arrayfun(ffun,XX,YY,ZZ);
```

This will return `f(i)=ffun(XX(i),YY(i),ZZ(i))` for each `i` in `1:numel(XX)`, which I think is what you are after. The output `f` will have the same shape as your input arrays, which seems perfectly fine to use with `isosurface` later.